# Question answered after having been closed

Tags: discussion

The question [how to choose resistors' value for common emitter amplifier?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/127491/4512) was closed (at the time of this writing) 1 hour ago, yet [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/127517/4512) was written 5 minutes ago.  How is this possible?  I thought closing a question prevents new answers.  I have had answers I've written rejected when the question was closed before I posted them.

Apparently I have a micconception about closing and answering.  Please enlighten me.

Comment: At a glance, this looks like some kind of a glitch.  I'll see if I can find out more about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this asked a few times on Meta.SE and I believe this answer is still current:

[How was this answer posted after this question was closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/how-was-this-answer-posted-after-this-question-was-closed)

The message that you see not allowing an answer to be posted happens on the client side of things, the server allows a grace period of around four hours. So one likely cause is that Jim had it open in his browser for some time and that check failed. Or maybe he did the same using the mobile version of the site that according to that answer doesn't have that check.

The real-time updates you see on questions (votes can change without refreshing etc) use a [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) on modern browsers but some operations fall back to [XHR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) on older browsers. Looking at the JavaScript involved I had a bit of a problem understanding some aspects, but from what I could work out the ability to post seems to get disabled in the client browser as a result of a message back from the server so if that fails (WebSocket is closed / times out while the page is still open) you can still post an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Very interesting.  I know you've had rejections after the question was deleted, but that's a different issue.  Maybe if you have the answer open before it was closed (I'd assume that's the only way, as there's no answer field available on a closed question) they'll let it through if it was simple closed and not deleted.

The other option is that the SE gods have heard your pleas on the issue and changed policy ;)

Comment: I suspect that the answer was initiated before the question was closed.  It took Jim a while to write the answer (maybe he got sidetracked).  By the time he had submitted the answer, the question got closed.  The back end had accepted the answer.  From what I was able to find out, this is a [not yet documented] feature that's coming around.

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way.  As I said in the question, I've started answering a question, then was unable to post the answer because the question was closed while I was writing.  This happens to me a few times a month, so I know the system works like that.